# Extra line in nested enumerate compiles, but only when inside a section

Tags: sectioning, lists, enumerate

Why does this compile:

```
\section{Section}

\begin{enumerate}
\item List item
    \begin{enumerate}
    Note
    \item Nested list item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

But this does not:

```
%\section{Section}

\begin{enumerate}
\item List item
    \begin{enumerate}
    Note
    \item Nested list item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

It gives the following error:

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Comment: It should also give the same error when it is preceded by `\section`, because there should be `\item` before "Note". And it does if there is any text between the `\section` command and the `enumerate`. So this looks like a bug.

Comment: The second is the expected, because the "Note" before the first item.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum On a related note, how would I let the item label appear on the line of the `Nested list item`, while keeping the `Note` above it at the same indentation?

Comment: `\item[] Note` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{enumerate}
Note
```

Is an error in both cases, however depending in the settings for your section headings the error may not be reported. LaTeX uses a special setting of `\everypar` to catch the paragraph starting with `Note` instead of `\item`, but section headings use special settings of `\everypar` to remove indentation of the first paragraph, and to restore normal setting after the first paragraph. These two uses can conflict.

Comment: The special `\everypar` to remove indentation of the first paragraph should probably be eliminated when there is a list after the `\section`. I experimented with this by putting `\everypar{}` in the beginning of `\def\@trivlist{`, and then the error message also appears in the first case. I think this would be a reasonable patch. However, I don't know if there are any bad side effects of such a correction. I don't have enough detailed insight in the LaTeX kernel to fathom all consequences. There might be even more places where such an `\everpar` would be needed.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum usual problem with any patch is its effect on contrib packages. changing tivlist after all this time... a bit scary:-)